# How to set the value of a form with #access = FALSE during validation?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form element with `#access = FALSE`.  I'm trying to set the value of this element during form validation using `form_set_value()`.  This works when `#access = TRUE`, but not when `#access = FALSE` (although even then the change is showing up in $form_state['values'].  I suspect later on in form processing the default form value is being used instead of the altered value in $form_state['values'].

How can I set this element's value during validation such that the correct value will be passed to the form submit handler(s)?

Comment: Just to make sure - you passed $form_state by reference (&$form_state, right ?). and make sure you set #value, and not #default_value.

Comment: I tried using `form_set_value()` for a form element with `#access` set to `FALSE`, and it works: The value the form submission handler finds in `$form_state['values']` is the value set with `form_set_value()`.

Comment: Thanks for verifying this worked for you kiamlaluno.  It's worked for me in the past as well.  The problem must lie elsewhere...